# creating a record with a has many through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I would like to create an association to another a model when creating a record.

The models use the has_many through association.

**Models**

**Recipe**

```
class Recipe < ApplicationRecord
  attribute :name
  attribute :published

  has_many :ingridients, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :instructions, dependent: :destroy
  
  has_many :recipe_seasons
  has_many :seasons, through: :recipe_seasons

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :recipe_seasons

  validates_presence_of :name
end
```

**Season**

```
class Season < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :recipe_seasons
    has_many :recipes, through: :recipe_seasons
end
```

**RecipeSeason**

```
class RecipeSeason < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :recipe
  belongs_to :season

  validates_presence_of :recipe
  validates_presence_of :season

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :season
end
```

Controller

```
  def new
    @month = 1
    @recipe = Recipe.new
    @recipe.recipe_seasons.build(season_id: @month).build_recipe
  end

  def create
    @recipe = Recipe.new(recipe_params)
    @recipe.save
    redirect_to recipes_path
    flash[:notice] = I18n.t("recipe.created")
  end

  private

  def recipe_params
    params.require(:recipe)
      .permit(:name, :published, recipe_seasons_attributes:[:recipe_id, :season_id ])
  end
```

When the Recipe is created, I'd like a defauly value of @month to be inserted into a record on the table recipe_seasons using the id of the newly created Recipe.

Form

```
<%= form_with(model: @recipe) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name, required: true %>
  <%= f.label :published %>
  <%= f.check_box :published, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Tick if done" %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
<%=link_to  t("back"), recipes_path %>
```

When I create a recipe, I would like a record to be inserted into recipe_seasons at the same time, using the id that is created on the recipe as the recipe_id on the table recipe_seasons. For now I will hard code a value for @month that is used for the season_id.

Answer (score 0):

You're actually overdoing and overcomplicating it here. You don't need anything in your RecipeSeason class except:

```
class RecipeSeason < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :recipe
  belongs_to :season
end
```

The presence validations are added by default to `belongs_to` assocations since Rails 5. You do not need nested attributes to just assign assocatiated items.

Normally when dealing with join tables you do not need to explicitly create the join models as they are created implicitly through the assocation:

```
def create
  @recipe = Recipe.new(recipe_params)
  # Always check if the record was valid and saved
  if @recipe.save 
    redirect_to recipes_path, status: :created
    flash[:notice] = I18n.t("recipe.created")
  else
    render :new
  end
end

def recipe_params
  params.require(:recipe)
        .permit(:name, :published, season_ids: [])
end
```

```
<%= form_with(model: :recipe) do |form| %>
  <%= form.collection_select(
    :season_ids, # name of the attribute
    Season.all,  # the collection which should be available as options
    :id,         # value method
    :name        # label method
  ) %>
<% end %>
```

This uses the setter created by `has_many :seasons, through: :recipe_seasons` and will automatically create/delete rows in the recipe_seasons table.

If you want to create a default you just set the `selected` attribute on the select element.

```
<%= form.collection_select :season_ids, @seasons, :id, :name, selected: @seasons.first.id %>
```

The only time you need to *explicitly* create the intermediate model is when its not just used as a simple join table and your passing properties for that table. For example if your have an order form and you want to add a product to the order together with a quantity:

```
# order.products << @product won't let us pass a quantity
order.line_items.create(
  product: @product,
  quantity: 50
)
```

That's when nested attributes actually becomes relevant.